# How can I dynamically change the og:title of my page

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-like

Essentially I have a website, which uses a query string to dynamically change the content depending on what the user enters into the url. I have also used a .htaccess file to rewrite the url to remove the question mark, so it looks like just another page. Example:

```
www.site.com/233 - loads content associated with the ID 233
```

My problem is that when someone likes the page on facebook, although I have used JS to change the url of the like to the current page, there is no way I can see (within my current coding ability) to dynamically change the og:url og:title etc. with the query string.

The outcome I want is that when someone likes my page, it shows on the news feed what content the user has liked. Example

```
user liked www.site.com/231 - instead of it showing just 'site' in the newsfeed
I wish it to show the extention, i.e 'site - content 231' for /231 and 'site -
content 4234' for /4234
```

Currently I have been forced to set a basic og:title and no og:url because obviously it is the same for each extension to the query string.

Comment: Create an router file that htaccess will point to, in this file create some var with template configs than include template, on template you can use these variables that was setted on router file.

Answer (score 0):

Simples explanation of my comment:

```
// router.php

// process URL and blah blah blah here

$config = array(
     "og" => array(
         "title" => "Cool Page"
     )
);
include 'template.php';


// template.php
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $config["og"]["title"]; ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```